# Angular directive templateUrl not working

Tags: angularjs, directive

This is my code so far, to return a view in browser via Angular custom directive, using @html.partialview

```
var newOne = function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "newone.html",
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            }]
    }
}
```

I declare the id "newone.html" here:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="newone.html">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/AngularTemplates/Newone.cshtml")
        </script>
```

and ofcourse I call the directive from the html:

```
<div data-new-one></div>
```

Unfortunately I do not get the appropriate response.
All I get is an error message(console inspector): 
**[$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: newone.html**

I tried to store the .cshtml in multiple folders, or even load it from bundleconfig... But nothing!
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Put that template in a HTML file or use the templateCache module.

Comment: First, it sounds like @html.partial is an ASP.NET command so you should add that as a tag in your question.  Also, you should check the developer console and ensure that the ``<script>`` with the HTML is actually being loaded by ASP.NET.  If it's blank or if ASP.NET is giving an error message, that's your problem.

Comment: Hi, try using the parameter `template` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use the @Html.Partial.

Try changing your directive code to this:

```
var newOne = function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "~/Views/AngularTemplates/Newone.cshtml",
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this didn't work. I don't get the error any more but neither the appropriate view returns as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in Angular documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt
which says:

> the template must have exactly one root element

Seems that multiple `<div>` tags or even comments are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file name named:

```
~/Views/AngularTemplates/Newone.**tpl**.cshtml
```

Just copy and past contents of old file into new `tpl.html` file
adding `tpl`(template) before the `cshtml` or `html`

Example:

```
stuff.tpl.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import template in the script and use it as a "template", not "templateUrl":

```
import newone from 'newone.html';
var newOne = function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: newone,
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        }]
      }
    }
```